# Передать файл и строку с помощью AJAX в PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#u_button').click(function () {
        var file_data = $('#u_jfile').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://example.ru/script.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: {
                class: $('#u_class').val(),
                subject: $('#subject').val()
            }, form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
if ( ( !empty( $_FILES[ 'file' ] ) ) && ( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'error' ] == 0 ) ) {
    $filename = basename( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ] );
    $ext = substr( $filename, strrpos( $filename, '.' ) + 1 );
    if ( ( $ext == "txt" ) && ( $_FILES[ "uploaded_file" ][ "size" ] < 350000000 ) ) {
        $newname = "../one/two/" . $_POST[ 'class' ] . "/" . $_POST[ 'subject' ] . ".txt";
        if ( ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $newname ) ) ) {
            $date = date( 'd.m.Y_H:i:s' );
            $newfile = "../one/two/{$_POST['class']}/{$_POST['subject']}/{$date}.bak.txt";
            if ( !copy( $newname, $newfile ) ) {
                echo json_encode( array( "status" => "FALSE", "message" => "Ошибка загрузки" ) );
                die();
            } else {
                echo json_encode( array( "status" => "TRUE", "message" => "Загружено" ) );
                die();
            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode( array( "status" => "FALSE", "message" => "Ошибка загрузки" ) );
            die();
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode( array( "status" => "FALSE", "message" => "cerr: ext or size" ) );
        die();
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode( array( "status" => "FALSE", "message" => "cerr: i not found file" ) );
    die();
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<label class="file_upload" id="u_file">
    <span>Выбрать файл</span>
    <input type="file" id="u_jfile" name="n_jfile" accept=".txt">
</label>
```

Сталкиваюсь с ошибкой:

> cerr: i not found file.

Comment: `echo json_encode( array( "status" => "FALSE", "message" => "cerr: i not found file" ) );` Вот отсюда ноги растут вашей ошибки. А вероятнее всего проблема в этом сравнении: `( !empty( $_FILES[ 'file' ] ) ) && ( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'error' ] == 0 ) ) `. Сделайте `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: Ее происхождение мне известно. Что вы имеете ввиду? Вообще, до внедрения ajax в проект, работало сносно.

Comment: Код пхп, который вы добавили в вопрос - там эти строки. Что значит её происхождение для вас неизвестно? И что именно вам непонятно, к чему относится "что вы имеете ввиду"? Если вам непонятна фраза "Сделайте `var_dump`" - это значит, что перед строкой `if ( ( !empty( $_FILES[ 'file' ] ) ) && ( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'error' ] == 0 ) ) {` в пхп нужно добавить строку `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: Часть кода (echo json_encode...), которую вы отправили, была добавлена мной. Возможно, я не понял вашей иронии. Да, вы верно поняли, именно это меня смутило.

Comment: Итак, ещё раз. Что вам возвращает `var_dump($_FILES)`?

Comment: Ничего. Совсем. Никакой реакции на нажатие кнопки.

Comment: @Marionette смотрите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791141/191745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в неправильной отправке данных в *data*. Вначале Вы правильно формируете *form_data*, что отправить файл как еcли бы была отправлена [обыкновенная форма с *encoding* установленным в *multipart/form-data*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData).
Для правильного `content-type` Вы ставите *[processData: false](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)*, но в *data* зачем-то ставите еще один объект, после чего в *data* получается "каша", которая не отправляется на сервер.

Правильно будет так:

```
$('#u_button').click(function () {
    var file_data = $('#u_jfile').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData;
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    form_data.append('class', $('#u_class').val());
    form_data.append('subject', $('#subject').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.ru/script.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form_data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: дополнительно можно убрать объявление ненужной переменной `var file_data = $('#u_jfile').prop('files')[0];` и вместо `form_data.append('file', file_data);` написать `form_data.append('file', $('#u_jfile').prop('files')[0]);`

Comment: К сожалению, проблема сохранилась. Та же ошибка.

Comment: @Marionette была пропущена строка при копировании `data: form_data,` обновили ответ

Comment: от ошибок удалось избавиться, правда, сообщение об успешной загрузке так же отсутствует.

Comment: @Marionette а что говорит консоль ?

Comment: Ничего, в консоли пусто.

Comment: error: function(data){ console.log('ajax err'  + data.message); } Добавив этот код, получаю ошибку "ajax err".

Comment: @Marionette ошибок быть не должно. Загрузите к себе и  проверьте пожалуйста как работают у Вас : [файл  html](https://pastebin.com/Kwi42ebP) и [файл php](https://pastebin.com/8bfgJTqx). Их работоспособность проверена.

Comment: Все, разобрался. Была установлена несуществующая директория. Благодарю вас за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("email", "Email пользователя");
data.append("message", "Какое-то сообщение");

// прикрепляем файлы
$.each($("#files")[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append("file[]", file);
});

// строим AJAX
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.href,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log('ОШИБКА: ' + textStatus );
    }
});
```

Comment: в чем отличие Вашего ответа от [существующего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791141/191745) помимо ненужно each (т.к. файл 1) ? :)

Comment: @Alex я предоставил код, который загружает все выбранные файлы, а не один, что бы следующим вопросом не было (как загрузить несколько файлов).

Comment: если так, то почему бы тогда уже не пояснить автору и серверную часть? Ведь если он загрузит несколько файлов у него будет возникать ошибка по его текущему коду и несомненно возникнет данный вопрос ))

Comment: @Alex не понимаю вопроса или претензию. Судя по Вашему вопросу, можно сделать правила для сервиса, что бы давали не больше одного ответа, так как они все похожи. Больше не комментирую Вас.

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли, это ни в коем случае не претензия или что-то в этом роде! Наличие нескольких ответов это очень хорошо, когда ответы не дублируют друг друга. В Вашем случае я попытался понять в чем отличие(т..к. его по факту нет). Увидев Ваше пояснение, я спросил почему бы не предоставить полный ответ, если Вы предугадываете следующий вопрос автора. Т.е. Вы говорите как сделать клиентскую часть по загрузке нескольких файлов, но совершенно не поясняете как сделать серверную, а без этого автор снова столкнется с ошибкой. Только и всего!

Comment: Полагаю, стоит вступить в дискуссию. @Владимир, вы не угадали, у меня нет подобной задачи. Понимаете, сначала я пытаюсь исследовать наиболее доступную информацию в интернете, а после, если ничего не вышло, пишу сюда. Впрочем, наверное, все так делают. К сожалению, я не так хорошо разбираюсь в языках. Есть базовый консольный уровень, может, еще что-то.

Comment: @Alex, большое спасибо. Воспользуюсь вашими рекомендациями. С теорией я знаком слабо, поэтому высказывание по типу "он пишет методом проб и ошибок" будет вполне обоснованно.

Comment: Если кто считает мой ответ ненужным, я не против его удаления.

Comment: @Владимир на Ваше усмотрение - на вопрос он отвечает и если вы хотели пояснить дополнительно как загрузить несколько файлов, рекомендую добавить серверный обработчик и написать, что это в т.ч. пример загрузки нескольких файлов. P.s.: искренне жаль если мой комментарий Вас обидел.

Comment: @Владимир, я не менее благодарен вам за помощь. Возможно, кто-то наткнется на эту тему и именно ваш ответ будет наиболее полезен.

Answer (score 0):

Найди отличия от своего варианта и найдеш ошыбку. Этот вариант работает верно.

Это первый файл `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>

<label class="file_upload" id="u_file">
    <span>Выбрать файл</span>
    <input type="file" id="u_jfile" name="n_jfile" accept=".txt">\
    <button type="submit" id="u_button">submit</button>
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        'use strict';
        $('#u_button').click(function () {
            var file_data = $('#u_jfile').prop('files')[0];
            var form_data = new FormData;
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            $.ajax({
                url: "script.php",
                data: form_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Второй файл `script.php`:

```
<?php
if ( !empty($_FILES['file'])  && $_FILES[ 'file' ]['error'] == 0 ) {
    $filename = basename( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ] );
    $ext = substr( $filename, strrpos( $filename, '.' ) + 1 );
    if ( ( $ext == "txt" ) && ( $_FILES[ "uploaded_file" ][ "size" ] < 350000000 ) ) {
        $newname = "test.txt";
        if ( ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $newname ) ) ) {
            $newfile = "test1.txt";
            if ( !copy( $newname, $newfile ) ) {
                echo json_encode( array( "status" => "FALSE", "message" => "Ошибка загрузки1" ) );
                die();
            } else {
                echo json_encode( array( "status" => "TRUE", "message" => "Загружено2" ) );
                die();
            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode( array( "status" => "FALSE", "message" => "Ошибка загрузки3" ) );
            die();
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode( array( "status" => "FALSE", "message" => "cerr: ext or size" ) );
        die();
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode( array( "status" => "FALSE", "message" => "cerr:qwedf i not found file" ) );
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Те поля (class, subject), что вы удалили, нужно обязательно передать, чтобы сохранить файл в необходимую директорию.

Comment: Для начала попробуй  запустить этот вариант, если при добавлении этих полей появиться ошибка тогда будеш знать точно место и причину. Так быстрее поймешь где было неверно